# Chrome Web Store API: Is it possible to set category via api?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to use Google [Chrome Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) to deploy chrome extension automatically. There is [API call to create](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#uploadnew) a new one and there is [API call to Publish](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#publishpublic)

But if I'm trying to publish just uploaded extension it returns an error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Publish condition not met: Please select a Primary Category for your item."}],"code":400,"message":"Publish condition not met: Please select a Primary Category for your item."}}
```

My questions is there a way to set "Category" programatically (via some other api API or in manifest.json)?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Note: Currently, there is no API for setting an item’s metadata, such as description. This has to be done manually in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard.